# Always centered responsive images

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I want to realize the following. Let's imagine 6 company logos vertically placed on desktop view. When I watch the site on tablet (or shrink the browser manually), 2 company logos jump to the next line, but I want them to be centered. And not floated to left, as all grid systems do. Is it possible somehow? Especially with Bootstrap?

My theory is, if I could know which images are in the second row, I could count then the offset from left, and move the images with js to a centered position. But only, if it is needed, so if 3 images jump to the new row, it's okay, nothing to do with them. Am I right?

Didn't found any solution or plugin knowing this specific feature.

Comment: Can you show is some code? [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use Javascript to do this but it would be better most of the time to do this using responsive breakpoints. So if your desktop grid classes are `col-md-2` and when going to a tablet size, two jump down, it would  usually be better just to make the logos `col-sm-4`, making 3 logos on each row.

If you notice only 2 images jump down on tablet, you could also add `col-sm-6` to just the last two to potentially center those images on the next row.